# Uploading image to rails app using carrierwave, android, and HTTPpost

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, rest, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am still learning a lot about Rails and Android development, so forgive me if my question is a bit unclear.

Fundamentally, what I'd like to do is uploading photos to my rails app using an android app.

I have a Rails app that uses Carrierwave and Amazon S3 for image uploading.  I'm writing a companion Android application app that can be used for updating entries on the site and for uploading photos.  I created a REST API for the rails app so that I can perform http post / get / and delete requests using the Android app, which is working for updating text entries.  But I'm unsure how to approach doing image uploading since when I look at the POST parameters in my Rails logs, it includes a lot of CarrierWave specific actions (such as @headers, @content_type, file, etc.).

Can anyone recommend a way for me to get started?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm having this issue at the moment - were you able to resolve yours?

Comment: I posted what I ended up doing as an answer below.  Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up piecing together code snippets and getting something that worked.  I had to send the image in a multipart entity:

```
public class uploadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, HttpEntity>{

        @Override
        protected HttpEntity doInBackground(Object... params){
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url= IMAGE_URL+"?auth_token=" + auth_token;
            Log.d(TAG, "image_url: " + url);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            MultipartEntity imageMPentity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            try{                
                imageMPentity.addPart("project_id", new StringBody(projectID));
                imageMPentity.addPart("step_id", new StringBody(stepID));
                imageMPentity.addPart("content_type", new StringBody("image/jpeg"));
                imageMPentity.addPart("filename", new StringBody(filename));
                imageMPentity.addPart("imagePath", new FileBody(new File(filepath)));       

                post.setEntity(imageMPentity);                

            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(StepActivity.class.getName(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                response = client.execute(post);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HttpEntity result = response.getEntity();
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(HttpEntity result){
            if(result !=null){
              // add whatever you want it to do next here
           }
        }     
    }
```

The asynctask requires a filepath and filename.  In my app, I allowed users to pick images from the gallery.  I then retrieve the filepath and filename like this:

```
@Override
// user selects image from gallery
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.d(TAG, "picturePath: " + picturePath);
            filepath = picturePath;
            filename = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(columnIndex)).getLastPathSegment().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "filename: " + filename);

            cursor.close();

            // add the image to the view
            addedImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }
    }
```

Hope that helps!